# MySQL only returns { first row } from the result of query !

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu

I've used my server for testing PHP & MySQL Applications long time ago.

Suddenly, **When i try to execute any query on the any table in any database, i get only the first row in the result of the query !**

I checked the configuration file, and didn't see anything strange there.

OS: Linux / Ubuntu 10.04 64bit Server Edition,
Web Server: Apache/2.2.14,
MySQL Client: 5.1.41,
MySQL Server: 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.3 (Ubuntu)

And, I'm **sure** that there's no error in my PHP Code, While **when i use phpMyAdmin, i get all rows normally !**.

Where should be the problem ?

Comment: Wanna show us the code anyway?  Just in case?

Comment: +1, code please, and what does mysql_num_rows() return?

Comment: >>And, I'm sure that there's no error in my PHP Code, While when i use phpMyAdmin, i get all rows normally !.

I like this line

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question.  If you're sure there's no problem with your PHP code, then there's no reason to post a question to a site where people solve problems in code.

Answer (score 7):

It would help if you posted your code, but I'm guessing that your code doesn't have a loop that fetches each row.

```
<?php

$Result = mysql_query( $Query );

while( $Row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $Result ) ) //keep going while there are more rows
{
    print_r( $Row );
}
```

mysql_fetch_accoc and mysql_fetch_array functions only return one row at a time (consecutively) so you need to run them for each row.

Comment: +1 I was typing a similar answer.  This would be my first guess, without seeing the code.

Comment: .. will the while loop finish when the fetch has returned all rows? What I mean is... if mysql_num_rows($result) returns 4, will the while loop run 4 times or infinite times?

Comment: mysql_fetch_accoc will return FALSE when there are no more rows. So the loop will keep going until it has read 4 rows (in this case) and then end. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 6):

The problem *is* with your code. You have just told us that phpMyAdmin returns from MySql fine, so clearly the MySql server is not the problem, nor is any part of the PHP server setup.

Your code is wrong, you probably have (inside your super confidential and perfect code) a limit 1 in your staement, or are grabbing the rows incorrectly because you are unaware of how mysql_fetch functions work.

Downvote me because I'm a snarky jerk, but whatever.